# How can I Output this code to a 'label' box

Tags: c#

Can i output this code/query to a label box? or is there a way to output this code on a label box?

```
        SqlConnection conn3 = new SqlConnection(connString);
        conn3.Open();
        string query2 = "select company_id from JO.dbo.Comp right join JO.dbo.Proj on Comp.company_id = Proj.company_id";
        SqlCommand getid = new SqlCommand(query2, conn3);
        getid.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
```

Comment: Yes you can but if youre expecting multiple output you should use a dynamically created label

Comment: You mean the SQL query or the result ?

Comment: the result of that query

Comment: 'ExecuteScalar();' Method will work if the output is just one row and one column

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ExecuteReader()` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery()` and then read your results into the label.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use ExecuteReader(), then

yourLabelBox.Text = result

( sorry for answering from mobile)